# How to have Google BigQuery properly detect header names?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

I successfully created a new table using the data I uploaded onto Google Cloud Platform's Storage, but the problem is the header field names are always wrong when I use the Automatically Detect setting, and set "Header rows to skip" to be 1...I just got generic names such as "string_field_0".

I know I can manually add field names under Schema, however, that is not feasible with tables that have many fields. Is there a way to fix the header names? It doesn't seem to be a big thing though...Pandas does this automatically all the time.

Thanks!

[image]
[image]

csv file in Excel:
[image]

Comment: What is your first row (header row) looks like?

Comment: @searain Thank you for your response. I've now updated my post with a new image.

Answer (score 13):

The problem is that you only have String types in your file. So, BigQuery can't differentiate between the header and actual valid rows. If you had say another column with something other than a String e.g. Integer, then it will detect the column names. For example:

```
column1,column2,column3
foo,bar,1
cat,dog,2
fizz,buzz,3
```

Correctly loads as this because there is something other than just Strings in the data:

[image]

So, either you need to have something other than just Strings, or you need to explicitly specify the schema yourself.

**Hint**: you don't have the use the UI and click a load of buttons for define the schema. You can programatically do it using the API or the `gcloud` CLI tool.

Comment: It is strange that BigQuery is not able to detect header or not proposing interface option to force the first row as header. BigLimitation for a BigAI company.

Comment: Agree that auto-detect needs work. But such comments aren't really constructive on SO. Maybe raise something on the public issue tracker instead.

Comment: Added https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/112210765 issue ticket on BigQuery, hopefully, will be more efficiently treated than my previously issue ticket :)

Comment: Can you please accept the answer so I can link to duplicate questions OP?

Answer (score 3):

Since it was not mentioned here, what helped me was to add 1 to **Header rows to skip.** You can find it under **Advanced Options**:

[image]

My database came from Google Sheet and it already had integer values in some columns.

Answer (score 1):

Same issue occurs with Google Sheets as well. Right, the cause is having all string data in the sheet. But the workaround is simple with Google Sheets; just adding an integer column as described [here](https://medium.com/@sametkaradag/bigquery-create-table-from-google-sheets-causing-incorrect-column-names-string-field-0-134f6ecd3fc8)