# Google BigQuery : "string_field_0" when I load data from Storage

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to use BigQuery's autodetect feature to load a semi-colon separated file from GCS, but it doesn't seem to be properly detecting my data and it names just one column as `string_field_0`

**What am I doing wrong?**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to have Google BigQuery properly detect header names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48590983/how-to-have-google-bigquery-properly-detect-header-names)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data has semicolons. BigQuery only support either comma, pipe or tab when using the schema auto detect feature. It's documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schema-detect).

So, you'll either have to manually specify it, or transform your data using one of those supported separators I listed above.

Comment: my data doesn't have semicolon but still give this string_field

Comment: if you're having trouble with detection in of headers in first row, try using both autodetect and skip-row (see [reference](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables#CsvOptions.FIELDS.skip_leading_rows)); passing `--skip_leading_rows=1` to `bq load` helped me. Just noticed that @EthanYanjiaLi posted a link to a similar solution.

Answer (score 2):

Please see this post, I think this is a problem on BigQuery side:
https://medium.com/google-cloud/bigquery-create-table-from-google-sheets-causing-incorrect-column-names-string-field-0-134f6ecd3fc8

Comment: This still seems to be true in October 2022.

Comment: Here's the corresponding [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/112210765) in Google's bug tracker