# bigquery table from GCS bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

When I load a table from GCS bucket to bigquery, it cannot detect the schema automatically. It gives me String_field_1, string_field_2 like this. How do i get the schema.I want to get the schema automatically. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to have Google BigQuery properly detect header names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48590983/how-to-have-google-bigquery-properly-detect-header-names)

Comment: This seems to be the same as https://stackoverflow.com/a/48593086/11866133 as Graham indicated. The BigQuery team is aware of this and are investigating improving it. You can follow their progress here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/112210765

Comment: Do you have a specific example for us to look at?

Comment: What is your file format in entry?